# datagridview update to database

Tags: sql, vb.net, datagridview

please help me...

I load my database in the datagrid view and edit some cells.
Now I just need to update my database

here are my codes

```
  Dim dT As DataTable = MyDB.ExecCommand("SELECT `Field Name` FROM `tblfield`", "wellsfargo").Tables(0)

    Dim sSQL As String = ""

    Dim dZ As DataTable = MyDB.ExecCommand("SELECT " & sColumn & " FROM `" + cboJob.Text.Trim + "`", "wellsfargo", 0).Tables(0)

    dColumn = New DataTable
    dColumn = MyDB.ExecCommand("SHOW COLUMNS IN tblrecord", "wellsfargo", 0).Tables(0)


    If dZ.Rows.Count <> 0 Then
        sSQL = "UPDATE " & sColumn & " FROM `" + cboJob.Text.Trim + "`"
        MyDB.ExecQuery(sSQL, "wellsfargo")
    Else
        Dim sColumn As String = ""

        For z As Integer = 0 To dT.Rows.Count - 1
            If z = 0 Then
                sColumn = "`" & dT.Rows(z).Item(0).ToString & "`"
            Else
                sColumn = sColumn & ",`" & dT.Rows(z).Item(0).ToString & "`"
            End If
        Next
        sSQL = "INSERT INTO `" + MyJob + "` (" + sColumn + ") "

        MyDB.ExecQuery(sSQL, "wellsfargo")
    End If
```

Comment: Can we get more details on what issue you are facing and what is actually unexpected to you ?

Comment: Thanks but I already finish it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done.
I used this codes..

```
 Try
        Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
        Dim sSQL As String
        sSQL = "UPDATE `" + cboJob.Text.Trim + "` SET `Description` ='" + TextBox1.Text + "' WHERE `Description`= '" + Label2.Text + "' AND `Line Number` ='" + comList.Text + "'"
        MyDB.ExecQuery(sSQL, "wellsfargo")
        MsgBox("Updated!")
        btnUpdate.Enabled = False

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Select table first to Update")
    End Try
    Cursor = Cursors.Default
```

Comment: I would suggest to verify either there is an update occured in database or not `before displaying a message` because Sometimes update statement runs but zero rows modifies. Also `MsgBox` is for VB6 for VB.Net `MessageBox.Show` uses.

Comment: oh.. i see.. how I can verify it?

Comment: It depends on how `MyDB.ExecQuery` is implemented. If it is implemented via `SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery` and this method returns an integer value, then a check for greater than zero value return will do it, like: 
if(MyDB.ExecQuery(sSQL, "wellsfargo")>0)then 
 'show message 
End if